# Typescript and nuxt memory leak with ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin

Tags: typescript, webpack, nuxt.js, fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin

I am trying to use typescript with nuxt but am getting the following issue when the site reloads in dev

*Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the memoryLimit option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration.
If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript or EsLint.*

Is there anyway to increase this in nuxt config?

Answer (score 6):

// In your webpack.config.js file

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  ...,
  plugins: [
    ...,
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      typescript: {
        memoryLimit: 4096,
      },
    }),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.  Note: I had to use ES6 import syntax: import ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin from 'fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin';

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find [some docs](https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/#typecheck) that indicate a possible solution - you can use the `typeCheck` option in your nuxt config.

And [here's the source code](https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/blob/85368409ab0aec9e763a24ad77ca17db129b4e6a/packages/typescript-build/src/index.ts#L77) where the merge takes place,

```js
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin')
config.plugins!.push(new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(Object.assign({
  typescript: {
    configFile: path.resolve(this.options.rootDir!, 'tsconfig.json'),
    extensions: {
      vue: true
    }
  },
  logger: consola.withScope('nuxt:typescript')
} as TsCheckerOptions, options.typeCheck)))
```

so providing the `typeCheck` option as an object with [properties known to the `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#typescript-options) should do the job:

```js
// The nuxt config file
{
 /* ... */
  typescript: {
   typeCheck: {
    memoryLimit: 2048,
   }
  }
 /* ... */
}
```